# How to split a list-of-strings into sublists-of-strings by a specific string element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, split

I have a word list like below. I want to split the list by `.`. Is there any better or useful code in Python 3?

```
a = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat', '.', 'hello', '.', 'she', 'is', 'nice', '.']
result = []
tmp = []
for elm in a:
    if elm is not '.':
        tmp.append(elm)
    else:
        result.append(tmp)
        tmp = []
print(result)
# result: [['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat'], ['hello'], ['she', 'is', 'nice']]
```

### Update

Add test cases to handle it correctly.

```
a = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat', '.', 'hello', '.', 'she', 'is', 'nice', '.']
b = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat', '.', 'hello', '.', 'she', 'is', 'nice', '.', 'yes']
c = ['.', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'cat', '.', 'hello', '.', 'she', 'is', 'nice', '.', 'yes']
def split_list(list_data, split_word='.'):
    result = []
    sub_data = []
    for elm in list_data:
        if elm is not split_word:
            sub_data.append(elm)
        else:
            if len(sub_data) != 0:
                result.append(sub_data)
            sub_data = []
    if len(sub_data) != 0:
        result.append(sub_data)
    return result

print(split_list(a)) # [['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat'], ['hello'], ['she', 'is', 'nice']]
print(split_list(b)) # [['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat'], ['hello'], ['she', 'is', 'nice'], ['yes']]
print(split_list(c)) # [['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat'], ['hello'], ['she', 'is', 'nice'], ['yes']]
```

Comment: It think there s a one-liner solution with no additional libraries that comes close to your speeds using list comprehension and string functions.

Comment: @ScottBoston I thought there was some useful functions :). But I'm happy to see many interesting answers.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `is` operator to compare strings BTW.

Comment: It appears you already split a string once. Your problem would be much simpler if your *first* split were by sentences.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
a = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat', '.', 'hello', '.', 'she', 'is', 'nice', '.']
result = [
    list(g)
    for k,g in groupby(a,lambda x:x=='.')
    if not k
]
print (result)
#[['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat'], ['hello'], ['she', 'is', 'nice']]
```

Answer (score 13):

You can do this all with a "one-liner" using list comprehension and string functions `join`, `split`, `strip`, and no additional libraries.

```
a = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat', '.', 'hello', '.', 'she', 'is', 'nice', '.']
b = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat', '.', 'hello', '.', 'she', 'is', 'nice', '.', 'yes']
c = ['.', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'cat', '.', 'hello', '.', 'she', 'is', 'nice', '.', 'yes']



In [5]: [i.strip().split(' ') for i in ' '.join(a).split('.') if len(i) > 0 ]
Out[5]: [['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat'], ['hello'], ['she', 'is', 'nice']]

In [8]: [i.strip().split(' ') for i in ' '.join(b).split('.') if len(i) > 0 ]
Out[8]: [['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat'], ['hello'], ['she', 'is', 'nice'], ['yes']]

In [9]: In [8]: [i.strip().split(' ') for i in ' '.join(c).split('.') if len(i) > 0 ]
Out[9]: [['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat'], ['hello'], ['she', 'is', 'nice'], ['yes']]
```

## [@Craig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7517724/craig) has a simpler update:

```
[s.split() for s in ' '.join(a).split('.') if s]
```

Comment: Slightly simpler: `[s.split() for s in ' '.join(a).split('.') if s]`

Comment: @Craig Thanks!  I hate when I over complicate and overthink things.

Comment: Oh, this is nice. But if there is a word which includes white space, `join` will break the original list. I mean like `"New York"`. I may add such a test case. But this is really simple and nice. Thank you!

Comment: @jef It is challenge to break 'This is New York.' into 'This', 'is', 'New York'.

Comment: This method is broken if any element has a space or a dot.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another way using only standard list operations (with no dependencies on other libraries!). First we find the split points and then we create sublists around them; notice that the first element is treated as a special case:

```
a = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat', '.', 'hello', '.', 'she', 'is', 'nice', '.']
indexes = [-1] + [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == '.']

[a[indexes[i]+1:indexes[i+1]] for i in range(len(indexes)-1)]
=> [['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat'], ['hello'], ['she', 'is', 'nice']]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reconstruct the string using `' '.join` and use regex:

```
import re
a = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat', '.', 'hello', '.', 'she', 'is', 'nice', '.']
new_s = [b for b in [re.split('\s', i) for i in re.split('\s*\.\s*', ' '.join(a))] if all(b)]
```

Output:

```
[['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat'], ['hello'], ['she', 'is', 'nice']]
```

Comment: Same comment as for @ScottBoston: This method is broken if any element has a space or a dot.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't help myself, just wanted to have fun with this great question:

```
import itertools

a = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat', '.', 'hello', '.', 'she', 'is', 'nice', '.']
b = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat', '.', 'hello', '.', 'she', 'is', 'nice', '.', 'yes']
c = ['.', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'cat', '.', 'hello', '.', 'she', 'is', 'nice', '.', 'yes']

def split_dots(lst):

    dots = [0] + [i+1 for i, e in enumerate(lst) if e == '.']

    result = [list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x : x != '.', lst[dot:])) for dot in dots]

    return list(filter(lambda x : x, result))

print(split_dots(a)) # [['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat'], ['hello'], ['she', 'is', 'nice']]
print(split_dots(b)) # [['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat'], ['hello'], ['she', 'is', 'nice'], ['yes']]
print(split_dots(c)) # [['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat'], ['hello'], ['she', 'is', 'nice'], ['yes']]
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer requires installing a 3rd party library: [`iteration_utilities`](http://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)<sup>1</sup>. The included [`split`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/split.html) function makes solving this task straightforward:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import split
>>> a = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat', '.', 'hello', '.', 'she', 'is', 'nice', '.']
>>> list(filter(None, split(a, '.', eq=True)))
[['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat'], ['hello'], ['she', 'is', 'nice']]
```

Instead of using the `eq` parameter you can also define a custom function where to split:

```
>>> list(filter(None, split(a, lambda x: x=='.')))
[['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat'], ['hello'], ['she', 'is', 'nice']]
```

In case you want to keep the `'.'`s you could also use the `keep_before` argument:

```
>>> list(filter(None, split(a, '.', eq=True, keep_before=True)))
[['this', 'is', 'a', 'cat', '.'], ['hello', '.'], ['she', 'is', 'nice', '.']]
```

Note that the library just makes it easier - it's easily possible (see the other answers) to accomplish this task without installing an additional library.

The `filter` can be removed if you don't expect `'.'` to appear at the beginning or end of your to-be-split list.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm the author of that library. It's available via `pip` or the `conda-forge` channel with `conda`.