# How to split a Python array at every occurrence of a given string?

Tags: python, slice

I am making up a code in Python 3.7 in which I need to split an array in chunks.

The array is something similar to the following one:

```py
['1.60500002', '1.61500001', '1.625', '1.63499999','NO',
'1.73500001','1.745', 'NO','2.04500008', '2.05499983']
```

I am interested to create n different slices (3 in this case) everytime the string `'NO'` occurs. Then the output array should be something like:

```py
[['1.60500002', '1.61500001', '1.625', '1.63499999'],
['1.73500001', '1.745'],
['2.04500008', '2.05499983']]
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Please share what you’ve tried so far and where you’re getting stuck.

Comment: You can use itertools groupby, try this answer, replacing '.' with 'NO': https://stackoverflow.com/a/47604467/12684122

Comment: Also, you can use list comprehenssion, with ```[i.strip().split(' ') for i in ' '.join(_list).split('NO') if len(i) > 0 ]```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a list-of-strings into sublists-of-strings by a specific string element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604449/how-to-split-a-list-of-strings-into-sublists-of-strings-by-a-specific-string-ele)

Answer (score 1):

You can try iterating through the list, checking if the element is a floating point number and if so adding it to a list and if not creating a new list. Just add up all the lists you've made and that should be it.

```
def split_str(inp):
    array_of_array = []
    arr = []
    for a in inp:
        try:
            float(a)
            arr.append(a)
        except Exception:
            array_of_array.append(arr)
            arr = []
    array_of_array.append(arr)
    return array_of_array
```

Answer (score 0):

loop over the array and if the element is "NO", we split the array until the "NO" element and add it to the output. if we reached the end, the last part would be from the last "NO" to the end.

```
my_array = ['1.60500002', '1.61500001', '1.625', '1.63499999','NO','1.73500001', '1.745', 'NO','2.04500008', '2.05499983']
    output = []
    counter = 0
    start = 0
    for item in my_array:
        if item == "NO":
            output.append(my_array[start:counter])
            start = counter + 1
        if counter == len(my_array) - 1:
            output.append(my_array[start:counter + 1])
        counter += 1
```

Comment: loop over the array and if the element is "NO", we split the array until the "NO" element and add it to the output. if we reached the end, the last part would be from the last "NO" to the end.

Comment: Please edit your question and put the explanation in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the only split indicator is 'NO' this should be easier. All you have to do is check for 'NO' and then create a new list. You also have to handle for the first element scenario as it can be a 'NO' or a number but creation of a new list if it is 'NO' is not required

To create a new list inside a list, you can do `examplelist.append([])`

Then to access a specific list inside a list, you can mention the list number in square brackets before using append(). eg. `examplelist[list_number].append(whatever)`

Here is the code I came up with :

```py
#Input
array = ['1.60500002', '1.61500001', '1.625', '1.63499999','NO','1.73500001', '1.745', 'NO','2.04500008', '2.05499983']
#Declaring
result = [] #empty list
list_number = 0 #to access a specific list inside a list
starting_element = True #var to handle starting scenario
for element in array:
    #starting scenario
    if starting_element:
        result.append([])
        if element != 'NO':
            result[list_number].append(element)
        starting_element = False
    #NO scenario
    elif element == 'NO':
        list_number += 1
        result.append([])
    #Number scenario
    elif element != 'NO':
        result[list_number].append(element)

print(result)
```